# Raspberry Pi 5 Servo Jitter

Tags: pwm, servo, pi-5

I’m trying to control 2 MG996R servos with my Pi 5.

I’m using gpiozero and python.  I’m using GPIO12 and GPIO13.  I have a separate 5v power supply to power the servos.

The servos both move but jitter A LOT!

My endless trawls of the internet indicate that the jitter is due to the gpiozero being software PWM rather than hardware PWM.

Also I see that there is no Hardware PWM HAT for the Pi5.

Is there any hardware PWM device I could use to smoothly operate the servos, that I could buy and control via the PI 5?

Comment: Software Ideas: Not sure this will help, but you might try switching from Python to a compiled language such as C. C will run much faster than Python. I believe over 100 times as fast and more. Also, you might try a minimal Linux distribution which runs less background processes (I assume you don't need such things as a CUPS printer server). Also, depending on how your servos behave, once the desired position is reached, stop sending the signal will quite most servos.

Comment: Look for a Pca9685 based board.

Comment: the title of your post does not match the question... please correct it

Comment: Currently there is no hardware PWM on Pi5. The easiest and probably cheapest solution is to use a Pico to control servos.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_servo_pulsewidth) using the 'pigpio' helps a lot.

Another cause of jitter could be the dynamic CPU clock, so you could set 'arm_freq=1500' and 'arm_freq_min=1500', in /boot/config.txt to set a fixed clock on the PI 5. Check the possible parameters [here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html).

Raising the priority of the Python script with a negative 'nice' value will also help.

Comment: pigpio does not work on the Pi5.

Comment: @joan I hope that minimal Pi5 support will be available in pigpio soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Install the necessary Python libraries for controlling the PCA9685. One popular library is **adafruit-circuitpython-pca9685**.
Modify your Python code to use the PCA9685 library to control the servos instead of gpiozero's PWM.